# Which Rest Method should be used for the creation of child

Tags: java, spring, rest, http

In my code, there is a parent-child relationship between entities. Now I have to write the Rest API to create a child.

I am confused between POST and PUT methods. If I will look into master it is like updation in master so I have to go with the PUT method. If I will look into child it is like the creation of a new child.

Code:

```
@PostMapping("/master/{masterId}/child/{childId}")
public ResponseEntity<Void> insertChildDetail(
```

I am using the POST method but I am not sure about it.

Could you please let me know which method is better to use and why so that I can get a better understanding.

Comment: According to specification, `POST` is used to create an new resources and `PUT` is used to update existing resources. More at [PUT vs. POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)

Comment: @SudhirOjha That's not quite right... You should read the answers of the question you linked above. Also have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57970140/1426227). Both `POST` and `PUT` methods can be used for creating resources.

Comment: @cossiomolin your answer is very helpful for everyone who landed on your answer, I am also one of them. Yes I have given a link in my comments that contains more details than my comment. I generally use POST for creating new resources and PUT for update existing one. That's why I given a comment not as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Both [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) and [`PUT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) methods can be used to create resources. If your application generates resource identifiers on behalf of the client, then you should use [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) instead of [`PUT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) for creating resources.

To support it, I've quoted some parts of the [`PUT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) method definition below (highlight is mine):

> [**4.3.4.  PUT**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)
>
> The `PUT` method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload.  [...]
>
> If the target resource does not have a current representation and the `PUT` successfully creates one, then the origin server MUST inform the user agent by sending a `201` (Created) response.  If the target resource does have a current representation and that representation is successfully modified in accordance with the state of the enclosed representation, then the origin server MUST send either a `200` (OK) or a `204` (No Content) response to indicate successful completion of the request. [...]
>
> Proper interpretation of a `PUT` request presumes that the user agent knows which target resource is desired.  **A service that selects a proper URI on behalf of the client, after receiving a state-changing request, SHOULD be implemented using the `POST` method rather than `PUT`.** [...]

Now, find below some relevant quotes on the [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) method definition:

> [**4.3.3.  POST**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3)
>
> The `POST` method requests that the target resource process the representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's own specific semantics. For example, `POST` is used for the following functions (among others):
>
> [...]
>
> - **Creating a new resource that has yet to be identified by the origin server;**
>
> [...]
>
> If one or more resources has been created on the origin server as a result of successfully processing a `POST` request, the origin server SHOULD send a `201` (Created) response containing a `Location` header field that provides an identifier for the primary resource created and a representation that describes the status of the request while referring to the new resource(s).

While the [`201`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2) status code indicates that a new resource has been created, the [`Location`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) header indicate where the newly created resource is located. If no [`Location`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) header is provided, then the client should assume that the resource is identified by the effective request URI:

> [**6.3.2. 201 Created**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2)
>
> The `201` (Created) status code indicates that the request has been fulfilled and has resulted in one or more new resources being created. The primary resource created by the request is identified by either a `Location` header field in the response or, if no `Location` field is received, by the effective request URI. [...]

Comment: could you please explain this sentence "A service that selects a proper URI on behalf of the client"

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the scenario. IMHO, creation is higher priority than update. So `POST` method is more standard than `PUT` method.

Comment: need more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`PUT` would make more sense when looking from the parent Object's perspective.

```
Parent -> Child
```

Since parent already exists, the child is an updation to the parent object.
So, I'd say `PUT` would be more appropriate.

```
POST -> create
PUT -> create/update
```